# Post data from ASP website to PHP website

Tags: php, asp.net

I am developing an opt-in/opt-out API for Mobile numbers which can be placed at the top of any website, so people can subscribe to receive an SMS to their mobile numbers.

I have the below script which basically post data between my PHP websites USING `Curl` which is working more than fine:

```
<?php

$url = "http://myserverurl.com/optin.php";
$postdata['customer_id'] = "1";
$postdata['mobilenumber'] = $_POST['mobilenumber'];

$useragent= "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" ;

$ch = curl_init();
//set some cookie details up (depending on the site)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); //set our user agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //set how many paramaters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); //set the url we want to use
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata); //set data to post


$result= curl_exec ($ch); //execute and get the results
curl_close ($ch);
//print $result; //display the reuslt

?>
```

How to apply this approach if the website is in `ASP.net`? Is there anything similar to `Curl` in `ASP.net`?

Thanks,

Comment: How is it possible that [google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=curl+asp+.net) didn't get you [this result](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/994430-asp-net-equivalent-of-phps-curl/)? What have you tried before you asked?

Comment: @Vyktor, Thank you for your reply. Of course I have googled that before, but I posted my question here to get an accurate answer from professionals. Second thing, my experience in ASP.net syntax is little bit weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) which will make most of it possible for you, but not line by line.

Also, you COULD download [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and call it from your application (really not recommended when you have the option of WebRequest though... hehe)

Answer (score 1):

After few seconds of [googling](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=curl%20asp%20.net) you'll get [this result](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/994430-asp-net-equivalent-of-phps-curl/). Which shows example using [`System.Net.WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx).

And MSDN provides [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) how to send post data with it.